# Create pool using connection string nodejs mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure

I have been looking for a way to use mysql connection string to create a pool rather than using the credentials, this is so I can use the connection string from azure application settings, but so far could not find a solution.

I can create a pool this way:

```
pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 20,
    host: HOST,
    user: USER,
    password: PASSWORD,
    database: DATABASE,
    debug: false
});
```

But what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
pool = mysql.createPool(process.env.MYSQLCONNSTR_connectionstring);
```

I am using the module [felixge/node-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying with the connection string provided by azure mysql db which was in the format:

```
Database=DATABASE;Data Source=HOST;User Id=USERID;Password=PASSWORD
```

But it turns out this format was not supported and it worked when I used this:

```
mysql://USERID:PASSWORD@HOST/DATABASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source of `node-mysql`, unfortunately there is no way to create a pool with connection string.

Ref: [PoolConfig.js](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/6ad9f4b0cf40b563cb583b169bda531bdb731159/lib/PoolConfig.js)

I think you should parse the connection string, there are every necessary information in it.

For example:

```
let connectionString = 'mysql://user:pass@host/db?debug=true&charset=BIG5_CHINESE_CI&timezone=-0700';

// remove mysql://
connectionString = connectionString.substring(8, connectionString.length)

// Get user and password
let userAndPassw = connectionString.split('@')[0];
let user = userAndPassw.split(':')[0];
let password = userAndPassw.split(':')[1];

// Host
let host = connectionString.split('@')[1];
host = host.split('?')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was too thinking of doing that but it turns out it was possible to create a pool with connection string, but the format was different than that with which I had tried.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer is not clearly written i wanted to clarify. I specified the connectionLimit value in the query string and now it works :

```
let pool = mysql.createPool('mysql://xxx@xxx/xxx?charset=utf8mb4&connectionLimit=10');
```